# Bind ViewModel's property to UserControl's child control and itself DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

What I want to do is to bind my usercontrol's label to a property value in ViewModel.
But I also want to get notified when the label changed ( and to do other work like extract the label's new value to modify grid width and so on).

How to do this?

what I did is:

Have a viewmodel with an Voltage property, which is what I want to display.

UnitVm.cs

```
    private int m_V;
    public int VoltInVm
    {
        get
        { return m_V;  }
        set
        {
            if (m_V != value)
            {        
                Set<int>(ref m_V, value, nameof(Volt)); 
            }
        }
    }
```

and my usercontrol: Unit.cs

```
public partial class Unit : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VoltProperty =
                      DependencyProperty.Register("Volt", typeof(int), typeof(Unit),  
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, (o, e) => ((Unit)o).OnVoltChanged(o, e)));

    private void OnVoltChanged(double dVolt)
    {
            double dWidth;
            if (double.TryParse(strVal, out dWidth))
            {
                dWidth = dVolt / 380 * 100;

                if (dWidth > 100)
                    dWidth = 100;

                gridVolt.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(dWidth, GridUnitType.Star);
                gridVolt.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width = new GridLength(100 - dWidth, GridUnitType.Star);
            }           
    }
    public int Volt
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(VoltProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(VoltProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

the DependencyProperty of VoltProperty is defined, and the work I want to do is written inside OnVoltChanged.

I mean when accepting change from ViewModel, I can call OnVoltChanged.

To use the usercontrol of Unit in a main window:

```
    <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding UnitVm, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
        <Viewbox 
            <Label x:Name="lblVolt" Content="{Binding VoltInVm}" />
        </Viewbox>
    </DockPanel>
```

lblVolt binding to UnitVm context can update with new voltage values correctly.
But how to bind to DependencyProperty of Volt in Unit?
And is this the right way?

Thanks in advance.

Ting

Comment: Not sure what you actual problem is. You would use your control like `<local:Unit Volt="{Binding VoltInVm}"/>`. In the control's XAML you would use `"{Binding Volt, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. My problem is to know when a binding property from view model changes, so I can intercept it and do something more (than updating a label's content, which is in fact done automatically, not by me, and not known or customizable by myself).  Adding the DependencyProperty in this example is in order to use the OnVoltChanged method, which is the notification of data change from view model if I bind correctly - this is my direct problem, my binding to a label inside my usercontrol is already OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view model property setter is not implemented correctly.

It should look like shown below, i.e. use the correct property name `nameof(VoltInVm)` and probably not check `m_V != value` before calling `Set`, because that is already done by the `Set` method.

```
private int voltInVm;

public int VoltInVm
{
    get { return voltInVm;  }
    set { Set<int>(ref voltInVm, value, nameof(VoltInVm)); }
}
```

When you now bind the UserControl's property like

```
<local:Unit Volt="{Binding VoltInVm}"/>
```

the PropertyChangedCallback of the `Volt` dependency property will be called each time the `VoltInVm` property changes its value.

It is however unclear what `(o, e) => ((Unit)o).OnVoltChanged(o, e)` in the dependency property registration is supposed to be. It should certainly look like this:

```
(o, e) => ((Unit)o).OnVoltChanged((int)e.NewValue)
```

and the method should be declared with an `int` argument instead of `double`:

```
private void OnVoltChanged(int volt) ...
```

Or - certainly better - change all voltage property types to `double`, in the control and in the view model.